# How to store result into csv file in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
meshcode2,result
30548625,218.14
30548616,318.75
30548616,404.53
30548616,343.85
30647133,78.43
30647133,125.53
30548615,314.68
30548615,314.68
30548615,264.50
30548615,264.50
30548626,98.03
30548615,166.04
30548615,114.12
30548615,104.67
30548616,470.25
```

I want to find median of this csv file and store in csv file so I did this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('001_meshcode2_result_sale.csv')
result = df.groupby('meshcode2').median()
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for data in result:
       writer.writerows(data)
```

When I open result file, I only received "result" letter, how to write the whole result into result.csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplier is add parameter `as_index=False` for column from `meshcode2` and then [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
result = df.groupby('meshcode2', as_index=False).median()
print (result)
   meshcode2  result
0   30548615  264.50
1   30548616  374.19
2   30548625  218.14
3   30548626   98.03
4   30647133  101.98

result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```